# Getting filename before saving in ActiveStorage - Rails 5.2.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I am trying to get the name of the file uploaded by a user before ActiveStorage goes on to save it. The form is generated using `form_with` and is shown below:

```
<%= form_with model: upload do |form| %>
  <div class="">
    <%= form.file_field :files, multiple: true, direct_upload: true, required: true %>
    <%= form.label :files, '', class: 'icon ion-ios-cloud-upload' do %>
      <span>click the icon to select files</span>
    <% end %>

    <div class="actions">
      <%= form.submit "Upload", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    </div>
 </div>
<% end %>
```

I have tried accessing `params[:upload][files]` and calling `.original_filename` on it as described [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#what-gets-uploaded) but I get the error `` NoMethodError: undefined method `original_filename' for #<String:0x007fac77fd18c8> ``.

The file does come back as a string when I inspect the params, so how do I get the filename or how do I get `original_filename` to work?

Comment: `original_filename` is one of the attributes of `ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile` not `ActiveStorage::Blob` https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Http/UploadedFile.html
https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#what-gets-uploaded https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveStorage/Blob.html#method-i-filename

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I was finally able to get the file name by doing `file.blob.filename` after the file had been attached.

Comment: Did you need `.blob`?  I didn't need it, and it didn't appear to make a difference for me.  Is there some benefit?

Answer (score 10):

Based on [the ActiveStorage documentation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveStorage/Blob.html#method-i-filename), I found this worked for me:

```
file.filename.to_s
```

In my case I have a model with

```
has_one_attached :file
```

OP's situation is slightly different and your situation may differ too, so adjust accordingly.

Troy's solution did not work for me as-is.  I had to add the `.to_s` to get the file name instead of an `ActiveStorage::Filename` object.  But I'm not sure why he's using `.blob` in there.  I didn't need it, but perhaps there's a good reason.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add `multipart: true` to your form.

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#uploading-files

The other thing is that if you have multiple files you'll have multiple filenames.

```
params[:upload][files].each do |file|
  file.original_filename
end
```

Comment: ```form_with``` already adds that, but I have tried adding `multipart: true` to the form and it doesn't work